# Not able to execute tests with @Test annotation when my test extends TestCase(Junit) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit4

Not able to execute tests with @Test annotation when my test extends TestCase(Junit) in Eclipse

It works fine when I am not extending from TestCase(jUnit), but my existing code extends from TestCase hence I would like to keep that as it is.

Answer (score 4):

Check that you are not using JUnit3 runner.

Open 'Run Configuration' for you test and on `Test` tab make sure you have `JUnit 4` selected for your test runner.

IMHO, if you are retrofitting your test suite for JUnit4, just drop support for JUnit3.

BTW, if you switch to 'JUnit 4' runner it will still execute old JUnit3 classes ( you don't have to add @Test annotations to them ).

Answer (score 4):

Tests that extend `junit.framework`. TestCase are considered to be JUnit3-style tests by the JUnit4 runner. This is correct.

To @Test annotation you need **NOT** extend `junit.framework`. TestCase and @Test annotation works fine

Answer (score 2):

Tests that extend `junit.framework.TestCase` are considered to be JUnit3-style tests by the JUnit4 runner. See [the source code](http://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/builders/AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java) for `AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder` for more details.

You could force JUnit4 to treat classes that extend `TestCase` as JUnit4-style tests by annotating the classes with `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` but you almost certainly do not want to do this. If you do this, your test classes would still inherit all of the methods from `junit.framework.TestCase` but those methods wouldn't be called. In other words, you would inherit a lot of cruft.

Inheritance is often a poor way to share code, even in tests. If it's possible to put the shared code in another class and delegate directly from the test classes, do that.

If you use JUnit 4.7 or later, [Rules](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules) provide another way to share code. Rules can be affected by or can affect the behavior of a test.

In very rare cases, shared code needed by multiple JUnit4 test classes can be shared in a Runner, but since a test class can only specify one runner, runners have many of the same disadvantages as base classes.